# Non-symmetric confidence intervals for bounded integer distribution

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm currently trying to estimate some properties of a Gacha game. I can simulate N draws over T time-steps and get a matrix $C \in \{0,....,C_\text{max}\}^{N \times T}$ where $C_{i,t}$ corresponds to the number of successful draws in the $i$-th trial up to time-step $t$. You can only get a maximum number of successes $C_\text{max}$, so the range of values is limited. This means that my distribution is very non-symmetric, and for each trial $i$ the probability of $C_{i,t}$ being equal to $C_\text{max}$ goes to 1 as $t \rightarrow \infty$. For me, $C_\text{max} = 7$. For low $t$, we have a one sided distribution as you will mostly have 0 successes:

[image]

Then we are somewhat symmetric at $t=100$:

[image]

And from there on become more and more centered around $C_\text{max}$ with decreasing variance, for example at $t = 200$ and $300$ it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Now I want to plot the mean number of successes across trials as a function of $t$ with some confidence interval around it to visualize this diminishing variance. Now as my distributions are non-Gaussian, I don't want to just fit a normal distribution at every timestep as it doesn't fit the data. Do you have any recommendations for a meaningful score to use here? I don't really mind if it's parametric or non-parametric.

Comment: Possibly an answer:  If you want to treat each time period individually, you can a bootstrapped confidence interval for the mean of each time period, such as with the percentile method.  With this method, the confidence interval won't go outside the range of observed values. ...  However, I'm not sure that the best method for what you want to do is to treat each time period individually.

Comment: I just computed the smallest interval around the mean for every time step t. Like quantiles, it's a stair function because all data are integers, but I guess confidence intervals for integer data are naturally also from integer to integer. Doesn't look smooth as I'd want it but I don't really know any better solution for now. And yeah, you're right that doing it per t is kinda unstable unless you have tons of samples.